# Get input Array Laravel not working

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, backbone.js, laravel

I'm creating an array of input in my form. And i wanna get this array on my controller in Laravel.

My inputs is hidden type, and i add this fields dynamically through JavaScript, using Backbone.

I add this inputs on my form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id_poi[]" class="id_poi" value="">
```

The value is also set dynamically in JavaScript.

After i add this input, this is my DOM:
[image: DOM]

So, i can add many inputs on my form.

When i'll handle this array on Laravel, i just get the value of the last input of this array.

I'm testing in this way:

```
public function store() {
    var_dump(Input::all());
    return;
}
```

And i had this output:

[image: Test post vars]

What i'm doing wrong to fail to get the values in an array?

**EDIT:**

I had other element with the same name in my form, and i change it.
But the problem isn't solved yet, when i submit the form, the elements added dynamically isn't sent to PHP. Resulting in the same output above.

Comment: Do you have another form element with the name of "id_poi"?

Comment: You're right, i had other element with the same name.

But the problem isn't solved yet, when i submit the form, the elements added dynamically isn't sent to PHP. :(

Comment: Something is not clear to me. Are you using Backbone to manage views and send data to the back end? If so, then why don't you store the data as properties to the view object instead of inserting them in the DOM as hidden input fields?

Comment: @KimGysen, really good idea, i really like that. But, the thing is, i had some blocks, where the user can reorder this blocks. That's why i need put this things on DOM.

Comment: How do you send the form, via the regular form POST method? Where is your <form> element relative to your new inputs? Are the hidden inputs inside the <form> tag?

Answer (score -1):

inputs is hidden name edit. Example

```
name="id_poi[0]"
name="id_poi[1]"
```

Sory, my English not good.

Comment: That's not necessary, `id_poi[]` should be fine.

Comment: javascript attach DOM problems

Comment: No idea what you are referring to, the screenshot shows that the elements are inserted correctly.

Comment: May be caused by a web browser. Need to test a different web browser. Without considering the first **id_poi[]**.